# how to hide version and name in mysql/mariadb?

Tags: mysql, security, mariadb

How to to hide the version and name of mysql/mariadb server at connect time? Is it possible? I've tried researching but found no solution to this.

While connecting with telnet I receive

5.5.5-10.2.10-MariaDB#KJ*$(&;mysql_nativ
e_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.

Is this displayed info possible to change to something more generic?

Comment: Why? Even if you do that, the user can still do `SELECT version();`

Comment: MariaDB isn't a telnet server. Its not intended to be parsed this way.

Answer (score 0):

The server has a read only system variable [version](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#version) that can be set in the configuration file to hide the server version. This is available 10.2.1 onwards.

In a config file

```
[mariadbd]
version=11.2.5
```

Or command line option:

```
$ mariadbd ... --version=11.2.5
...
Version: '10.6.1-MariaDB' as '11.2.5'  socket: 'Systemd socket activated ports'  port: 0  Source distribution
```

From the client:

```
mariadb -e 'select version()';
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 11.2.5    |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Important to note, just because you can do this doesn't mean its a good idea. If you're trying to make it compatible to programs that insist on a particular version its ok, even if a rather brutal setting to do this. If you think you gaining a security benefit you aren't, an exploit attempt can just ignore the version.